# I was getting 3 errors when following a tutorial and I don't know how to fix them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

These are my 3 errors that I have:

Assets/Scripts/Controllers/PlayerController.cs(13,27): error CS0115: 'PlayerController.RetrieveMoveInput()': no suitable method found to override

Assets/Scripts/Controllers/PlayerController.cs(8,26): error CS0115: 'PlayerController.RetrieveJumpInput()': no suitable method found to override

Assets/Scripts/Controllers/PlayerController.cs(6,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InputController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This was the video I was watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcw6nuc2uaU&t=140s

These are my 2 scripts:

InputController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Input : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract float RetrieveMoveInput();
    public abstract bool RetrieveJumpInput();
}
```

PlayerController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "PlayerController", menuName = "InputController/PlayerController")]
public class PlayerController : InputController
{
    public override bool RetrieveJumpInput()
    {
        return Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
    }

    public override float RetrieveMoveInput()
    {
        return Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

}
```

Sorry if I've not formatted this correctly, haven't been on here in so long!

Comment: This is a typo. You’ve inherited `InputController` when you should have inherited `Input`.

Comment: Sry im pretty knew to unity what do u mean by inherit?

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec means replace `InputController` by `Input` as in `public class PlayerController : Input { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a typo depending on how you want to view it should be either:

```csharp
//wrong class declaration
 public abstract class Input : ScriptableObject
{...}
//correct class declaration (how it is written in the github of the tutorial)
 public abstract class InputController : ScriptableObject
{...}
```

alternatively you could also do

```csharp
//corrected class declaration in other script
public class PlayerController : Input
```

However I would advise against that and use the tutorial variant, because `Input` is already a default Unity class that is used for input devices and you'll just be confusing yourself and the compiler.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: @derHugo to the reporting office we go!

Comment: Of course u should because then that person who has a typo will never find out where or what the typo is lmao